# How to design "like on posts" in relational databases?

Tags: mysql, modeling, erd

I'm developing a kind of social app, where an user can write a `post`, and give `like` on other posts.

And on the frontend users can see how many likes a post has.

In this case, how can I handle the count of likes for each post?

What I've been thinking so far is...

(1) maintain the `post_likes` table whose primary keys are `user_id` and `post_id`. Everytime users give like on a post, a new row is appended on the table. The count of likes are calculated from counting the corresponding rows of `post_likes` table.

(2) `posts` table has a `like_count` column. Everytime users give like on a post, the value of the column increases by 1. The count of likes are calculated from selecting `like_count` value.

I think that the implementation (1) would be better in that which user gave like to which post. However, it seems that it could be inefficient since `select COUNT(*)` should be executed in order to get the like count whenever users requests a page.

what is the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches have their pros and cons, but I think approach (1) is a better option for several reasons:

- You can prevent users from liking their own posts (if you want to implement that).
- You can allow users to remove their like.
- You can prevent one user liking a post multiple times.

If performance is an issue you can opt for a new table `post_likes_count` that will periodically be updated from `post_likes` with the new like count for a post. Again, keep in mind it depends on what you specifically want to accomplish.